# Generating a user unique hash

Tags: android

I need to generate an hash, that is unique for a user on an android device. Since they can have multiple users that seems difficult to me. I was about to use the IMEI of the device (or another device, if there is one), but since android supports multiple users, I have to use something else, without changing my permissions if possible (at the moment I have internet and read/write storage permissions)

Any Ideas?

For hashing itself I would use MD5 or SHA1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a UUID and store it on the device, [as is recommended by Google](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html).

Comment: I was hoping there's a way to generate an unique ID, which I don't have to store, but generates the same all the time.

Comment: @Unicate: You are welcome to try `ANDROID_ID`, but it is risky. Beyond the problems illustrated in the blog post I linked to, rooted devices and ROM mods to not necessarily use unique `ANDROID_ID` values, and users could change `ANDROID_ID` values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using OpenUDID on all platforms, it works pretty good! https://github.com/vieux/OpenUDID